# Where did the update notifications for Java and Safari 6.0.4 go?

Tags: safari, mac-appstore, java

Yesterday my Apple Store came up with the list of new updates available, including Java and Safari 6.0.4.

Since it was late I decided to wait till this morning to do the update. Now the same list does not show the Safari or Java update. So what happened?

I cannot find those updates on Appple websites.

Can someone help me finding these latest updates?

Answer (score 2):

### Java Update

See [DL1572](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) for details.

[image]

### Safari Update

Gets pushed via Software update (and installed automatically if the system has been set to download and install updates automatically).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is an OLD update. I was looking for the newest version released on April 16, 2013.

Comment: It's not old. Check the right side of the page. You will find April 16th 2013.

Comment: Strange, I only see the March. 4 Ver 1.6.0_43 there.

Comment: See the screenshot.    http://s22.postimg.org/9mjug07bh/Screen_Shot_2013_04_18_at_7_21_25_PM.jpg